# How to make a filter attached to $scope of a controller (angular)?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I wrote a litlle program in angular using ui-select. And I wrote a filter that do an OR search in different fields.

Here is my **original** filter : (whic works perfectly)

```
app.filter('orSearchFilter', function($parse) {
return function(items, props) {
  var out = [];

  if (angular.isArray(items)) {
    var keys = Object.keys(props);

    items.forEach(function(item) {
      var itemMatches = false;

      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var prop = $parse(keys[i])(item);
        var text = props[keys[i]].toLowerCase();

        if (prop && prop.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
          itemMatches = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (itemMatches) {
        out.push(item);
      }
    });
  } else {
    out = items;
  }

  return out;
};
});
```

And here is my original plunker (which works) : http://plnkr.co/edit/IdqO5dtLXmC6gtqLxRdP?p=preview

The problem is that my filter won't be generic and I will use it in my final code just inside its controller. So, I want to attach it.

Here is the **new** version of the filter which is attached to the controller : (I didn't do any change...)

```
  $scope.orSearchFilter = function($parse) {
    return function(items, props) {
      var out = [];

      if (angular.isArray(items)) {
        var keys = Object.keys(props);

        items.forEach(function(item) {
          var itemMatches = false;

          for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            var prop = $parse(keys[i])(item);
            var text = props[keys[i]].toLowerCase();

            if (prop && prop.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
              itemMatches = true;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (itemMatches) {
            out.push(item);
          }
        });
      } else {
        out = items;
      }

      return out;
    };
  };
```

Finally, in my html, I called this new filter by using this line :

```
    <ui-select-choices group-by="groupByLetter" 
repeat="contract in (contracts |
filter : orSearchFilter(contracts, {id.id: $select.search, policy.info.name : $select.search } )  |
orderBy: 'name') track by contract.name">
      {{contract.name}} - {{contract.value}} ---- {{contract.id.id}} *** {{contract.policy.info.name }}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Can you help me please to fix that problem and help me to attach this filter to the scope of the controller?

Thank you !

Comment: What is your use case to do it this way? It's rather odd

Comment: it's just to don't make it a generic filter (because I already know that I will use it only a few times and only inside the controller). It's why I want to attach it to the scope of the controller !

Comment: IMHO it doesn't make much sense, you already have the filter that can be easily accessed in template `{{ whatever | orSearchFilter:searchObject}}` or in javascript `$filter('orSearchFilter')(whatever, searchObject)` and adding some extra logic in controller will just pollute the code with something that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$filter service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) to programmatically fetch your filter function.

```
//Don't forget to inject $filter in your controller ofcourse
$scope.orSearchFilter = $filter('orSearchFilter');
```

Comment: The problem is not to use the filter in the javascript side but in the html side....

Comment: @salamanka44 You're already using it in your view in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the filter directly to scope:

```
/* REMOVE constructor function
  $scope.orSearchFilter = function($parse) {
    return function(items, props) {
*/
// INSTEAD
  $scope.orSearchFilter = function(items, props) {
      var out = [];

      //...

      return out;
    };
//};
```

Of course, also be sure that `$parse` is added to the injectables of the controller construction function.